# How to setup master password for login as user in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

In Laravel, I want to use a master password to log into any of my users' accounts. This is what I want to try

```php
if (Input::get('password') == 'master_password') {

    $email = Input::get('email');
    $user = User::find($email);
    Auth::login($user);

    return Redirect::intended('/account')->withInput();
}
```

But don't know where is controller in which I have to paste it

Comment: Master's password seems an odd method to do that. Try to look into what is said here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34292413/allow-admin-users-to-see-what-other-user-type-can-see-do You use your admin account, "pretend" you're other user and still allows you to go back to your admin account after

Comment: You have to paste it in your login controller.